# SQL - How to select the row that has specific condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I am a newbie in SQL world and I'm using MariaDB 10.1 in Windows 7.

Here's the test code I've created.

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
    studentName VARCHAR(32),
    subjectName VARCHAR(16),
    subjectRegistration BOOLEAN
);

INSERT
INTO    sample VALUES
    ("Tom", "Math", TRUE),
    ("Tom", "English", TRUE),
    ("Tom", "Science", TRUE),
    ("Jane", "English", TRUE),
    ("Jane", "Math", TRUE),
    ("Jane", "Science", TRUE),
    ("Peter", "Math", TRUE),
    ("Susan", "Math", TRUE),
    ("Susan", "Science", TRUE),
    ("Clark", "Math", TRUE),
    ("Clark", "English", TRUE),
    ("Clark", "Science", TRUE);
```

**I want to select the student who only enrolled Math.** (In this case, it's Peter.)

`SELECT * FROM sample WHERE subjectName = 'Math' AND subjectRegistration = TRUE;`

This query selects not only Peter but everyone who enrolled other subjects.

What query should I use?

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is include students who have taken **only** math. There are several variations on how to do this in sql. The overall idea is to find out who took math and only took 1 course. These are just a few examples of how to do it but each will accomplish your task.

You can check each example at this [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c2486/1).

Example 1:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM sample 
 WHERE subjectName = 'Math'
   AND subjectRegistration = TRUE  
   AND studentName IN (SELECT studentName 
                         FROM sample 
                        WHERE subjectRegistration = TRUE
                       GROUP BY studentName 
                       HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

Example 2:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sample s
       JOIN (SELECT studentName 
               FROM sample 
              WHERE subjectRegistration = TRUE
             GROUP BY studentName
             HAVING count(*) = 1) s2 ON (s.studentName = s2.studentName)
 WHERE s.subjectName = 'Math'
   AND subjectRegistration = TRUE
```

Comment: Ah self join was key point! First one looks better to understand but I like join method. Thank you! XD

Answer (score 2):

I would use `not exists` :

```
select s.*
from sample s
where subjectRegistration = true and
      not exists (select 1 
                 from sample s1
                 where s1.studentName = s.studentName and 
                       s1.subjectName <> 'Math'
                 );
```